# Flutter Flare Teddy : I am Not able to Figure out how i can able to use Teddy | TrackingTextInput _controller and My controller both in TextField

Tags: flutter, flare

I have Extracted My TextWidget using like this To achieve my Custom UI TextField but not able to figure out where i can use Teddy _controller !? (because i am using my controller for input and password... to get and use it.)

Code...

In My Login Page..

TrackingTextInput(customTextWid: CustomTextWid(focusNode: _focusNode, controller: _controller, workSansSemiBold: workSansSemiBold, envelope: _envelope, emailAddress: emailAddress)),

In trackingtext_input.dart

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only( top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0), child: widget.trackBuildWid);

added customTextWid Parameter and succefully able to use and Show UI in app by returning my custom widget in Parameter in build of trackingtext_input.dart,
but how and where i need to use Teddy _controller to animate Teddy !

I am Trying to implement in this Login UI
https://github.com/huextrat/TheGorgeousLogin

Any clue or help will be highly Appreciated !

Thanks in Advance !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just Use _teddyController, don't get confuse with _textController.